# Authenticating a user the "right" way - do I need to access the user password from db?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passwords

I'm trying to implement user authentication, and on my server I am doing the following for login:

Query the user email/password from the request body's email/password.  So, my select query will return me something like:

[image]

I'm storing the password after running it through bcrypt.  Now if the user's password from the req.body is "kittycats", should I be doing a comparison between `req.body.password` and `db.password` using bcrypt's compare?

I'm new to this kind of stuff, so I don't know if that is considered a "good practice" or if I'm doing this totally wrong.

Thanks

Comment: There is no “bcrypt's decode” - bcrypt is a _hashing_ function.

Comment: Hash their input with bcrypt and compare the result with what is stored in your database.

Comment: sorry I meant bcrypt compare.  sorry still learning

Answer (score 0):

Yes the compare function allows to verify a password with a stored hash. Actually I'm not familiar with the node.js library but I assume this is the API documentation:

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-check-a-password

The compare function works like any other BCrypt libraries, it extracts the salt and the cost factor from the stored hash and calculates a comparable hash from the password. Then it checks whether the stored hash and the calculated hash are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [passport.js.](http://passportjs.org/)

You can devise a local strategy in passport.js for authentication purpose. There is a NPM package available for the same. Check it out at [passport-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local).

From you questions, it looks like you are using SQL database. I am not sure how to user passport with SQL database. There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066094/how-to-configure-passportjs-with-sql-server) which talks about using the passport with SQL. Please check it out.

I can show you how I use passport.js with mongoose.

// My user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

// add this in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('/path/to/user/model');

passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username
      }),
      req.body.password,
      function(err, user) {
          passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
            return res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Registration Successful!'
            });
      });
    );
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    passport.authenticate('user', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) {
       //handle err
      }
      if (!user) {
        //user not found
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          //handle err
        }

        //Login successful! 
      });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Hope you find it useful!